# Make div fly across the screen

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, action

I have two bag images that I want to simultaneously fly across the screen. At the end they are going to disappear and then reappear in the different location, where they will stay unless the page is refreshed.

```
$('.main_carousel_bag').fadeOut(000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1500);  


$('.left_bag_action')
.animate({ left: '+=960', top:'-=400'}, 500)
.animate({ visibility: 'hidden'}, 0)
.delay(1000)
.animate({ visibility: 'visible'}, 0)
.animate({ left: '-=960'}, 1000)
.animate({ visibility: 'hidden'}, 0)
;
```

The main_carousel_bag is a div that is in the correct position regardless of window size. It fades in after a 4 second delay. This is working perfectly.

The left_bag_action is a div that starts on the left side of the screen (absolutely positioned) and then does the actions requested. The movements are working perfectly, however I want the bag to disappear while another (right_bag_action) flies across the screen in the other direction. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle with what you have until now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function, this is the code that is triggered when the animation is complete

eg...

```
$('.main_carousel_bag').fadeOut(000).delay(4000).fadeIn(1500);  

$('.left_bag_action')
.animate({ left: '+=960', top:'-=400'}, 500)
.animate({ visibility: 'hidden'}, 0)
.delay(1000)
.animate({ visibility: 'visible'}, 0)
.animate({ left: '-=960'}, 1000)
.animate({ visibility: 'hidden'}, 0, function(){
    //.....Some code here for right_bag_action....//
})
```